# Tuning query to remove joins for reporting

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, subquery, tuning

This is the query I was sent. There is currently no data in the system as I was converting this query from teradata to SQL server.

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT user_id , MIN(event_date) FROM event_table WHERE event_code='859' GROUP BY user_id
) join_859
ON user_table.user_id = join_859.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT user_id , MIN(event_date) FROM event_table WHERE event_code='223' GROUP BY user_id
) join_223
ON user_table.user_id = join_223.user_id
```

Would the following query return the same results and perform better?

```
SELECT user_table.user_id, event_table.event_date 
FROM user_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN event_table ON user_table.user_id = event_table.user_id 
WHERE event_table.event_code IN (
    '223', 
    '859'
)
```

Comment: `LEFT INNER JOIN` -- errr...

Comment: haha sorry, jon, I was typing it while looking at a different inner join on another screen.

Comment: If the only output is the `user_id` column, what is the purpose of the aggregate? And why bother including `user_table` in the query, even if the output should be `user_i9d, event_date_1, event_date_2`? Finally, don't use aliases that include keywords, e.g. `join_859` initially looked to me like a `join`.

Comment: Because the original query was very poorly formatted, and I simplified the query to what was really needed.

Comment: But do you see how transcription led to many more errors than would have resulted from copying and pasting and then editing here?

Answer (score 3):

No it wouldn't (that is, it's not logically equivalent. Performance would probably be better though). Two reasons:

- Both of the subqueries are aggregating to get the minimum `event_date`.
- The second subquery (`join_223`) is an `OUTER JOIN`, not an `INNER JOIN`.

Incidentally, you have a repeated `ON ON` in the last line of the original query.

Comment: They are both `left outer joins`, that was my bad.

Comment: Looking at the query in the question, it could simplify to `SELECT user_id FROM user_table`. The `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s will include all rows, and you're not actually doing anything with the `min_date` you calculate. Are you sure you've translated this correctly from your Teradata query?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you only need to do this:

```
;WITH x(user_id, event_date) AS 
(
  SELECT user_id, MIN(event_date)
    FROM dbo.event_table
    WHERE event_code IN ('223', '859')
    GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT user_id, event_date FROM x;
```

If you need other columns from the `user_table`, or you need to include rows from `user_table` even if they don't have any corresponding rows in `event_table`, then outer join *after* aggregating, but without all that repetition you currently have with derived tables:

```
;WITH x(user_id, event_date) AS 
(
  SELECT user_id, MIN(event_date)
    FROM dbo.event_table
    WHERE event_code IN ('223', '859')
    GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT u.user_id, x.event_date, u.other_columns
FROM dbo.user_table AS u LEFT OUTER JOIN x
ON x.user_id = u.user_id;
```

This also makes it very easy to expand to more or different `event_code` values (assuming you want the min event date, not the min event date *per* event code).

Now, you mention tuning, which to many will imply that the current query is slow. This won't necessarily speed it up all that much, since the slowness is probably not altogether the fault of your particular query, but rather your indexes (or lack thereof).

If you post the full schema, including indexes, and then a few rows of sample data (all cases, including source data that has users with only 223, only 859, neither, and both), and desired results from that sample data, it will be much easier to provide precise assistance. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is a great place to create schema and sample data.